# GTK InitError in Ruby

Tags: ruby, gtk

Trying to install and get some Ruby gems working on OS X 10.9.5 Mavericks. Currently getting this error, any help? No idea what's going on... Thanks!

```
.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gtk2-2.2.2/lib/gtk2.rb:13:in `init': Cannot open display:   (Gtk::InitError)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
gtk2.rb
```

On (or around) line:

```
:13:in
```

Error: Cannot open display:

```
(Gtk::InitError)
```

Reason for this error? Most likely the Gtk gem/library is not properly installed, or you are not instantiating the Gtk object properly or both.

You should update your question to include the content of `gtk2.rb` and we will be able to further assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby/GTK2 requires X Window System. Please install X11.app (XQuartz).

About X11 and OS X
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5293